# Cygwin : cannot install new package from updated local installation directory

Tags: cygwin

I choosed to provide a cygwin to be installed from a Local Directory. After building it, I wanted to add a new package inside, then re-running Cygwin Setup still with "Install from local directory" option.

I got a message :

> This setup.ini is older than the one you used last time you installed
>   cygwin. Proceed anyway? Yes/No

Clicking "Yes" leads to the package list. Sadly, the new one wasn't found.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply to self. The second execution of "Download without installing" put the new packages in a sub directory named according to the mirror used. Moving the package to the right path solved the problem.